# Building a mobile hybrid app with Ember.js

Tags: mobile, ember.js, ember-cli

For the last 6 years I have been developing with Ember.js framework. Now I need to develop a mobile app, both to Android and iOS, what are my options and most recent technologies to develop it using the Ember.js javascript framework?

I now there is cordova and also corber.io, are there any other frameworks/platforms?

Comment: [cordova/cober](https://github.com/isleofcode/ember-cordova)

Comment: PWA technologies are what power https://emberclear.io (an ember chat app)

Answer (score 1):

This project uses some PWA technology if that's of interest: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/emberclear

It has:

- automatic updates (sorta, 'click to update', like what Google Web apps do)
- caches downloaded resources for super fast load times.
- loads WASM for speed of calculation heavy things
- an app shell for perceived fast time to initial render
- is totally responsive / mobile first
- notifications (but not push notifications (yet?) Not sure if I want to add those yet)
- utilizes indexeddb for storing complex data on the device